# Angular Typescript: x is not a function Error

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**EDIT: Thank you to everyone who pointed out I had my code in the wrong place... LOL**

I've been struggling with this all day, the button is supposed to open the menu and change to "close menu" after displaying a 3 item list. It compiles fine in VSCode but when I run the website and inspect it, it gives me the error "changeMenuDisplay is not a function", but it's formatted correctly. What am I doing wrong? Quick answers please

**Typescript:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { FavVideoComponent } from './fav-video/fav-video.component';
import { PlaygroundComponent } from './playground/playground.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    FavVideoComponent,
    PlaygroundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  public myLinks: {name: string, value: number}[] = [
    {name: "About", value: 0},
    {name: "Video", value: 1},
    {name: "Playground", value: 2}
  ]
  public currDisplay = "";
  public showMenu = false;

  constructor() {
    this.currDisplay = "";
    this.showMenu = false;
  }

  switchContent(word: string) {
    this.currDisplay = word; 
  }

  changeMenuDisplay() {
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<main>
    <section id="menuSection">
        <button
            class="menubutton"
            (click)="changeMenuDisplay()">
            {{showMenu ? "Close" : "Open"}}
            Menu
        </button>
        <nav
            *ngIf="showMenu">
                <ol>
                    <li 
                        class="link"
                        (click)="switchContent(word)">
                        <button
                            *ngFor="let word of myLinks; let i=index"
                            [name] = "currDisplay"
                            (click)="switchContent(link)">
                            {{ word }}
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ol>
        </nav>
    </section>
    <section id="contentSection"
        [ngSwitch]="currDisplay">
            <app-about *ngSwitchCase="'About'"></app-about>
            <app-fav-video *ngSwitchCase="'Video'"></app-fav-video>
            <app-playground *ngSwitchCase="'Playground'"></app-playground>
            <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                <h1>Home</h1>
                <h2>Use the menu to click through the links.</h2>
            </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

I looked up solutions to fix this but nothing has worked and has continued to frustrate me.

Comment: Your function should be defined in a component, not in a module.

Comment: If the answer helped you, do not write thanks comment in your post. Accept or upvote or both.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your logic in `AppComponent`, not `AppModule`.
Assuming your html is `app.component.html`, you should write like this.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { FavVideoComponent } from './fav-video/fav-video.component';
import { PlaygroundComponent } from './playground/playground.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    FavVideoComponent,
    PlaygroundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {     // <-- not AppModule
  public myLinks: {name: string, value: number}[] = [
    {name: "About", value: 0},
    {name: "Video", value: 1},
    {name: "Playground", value: 2}
  ]
  public currDisplay = "";
  public showMenu = false;

  constructor() {
    this.currDisplay = "";
    this.showMenu = false;
  }

  switchContent(word: string) {
    this.currDisplay = word; 
  }

  changeMenuDisplay() {
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
  }
}
```